# Task Parallel Library WaitAll Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am working with the Task Parallel Library and I am using the Task Factory to create and start a list of new tasks. After starting the tasks, I make a call to Task.WaitAll(...) to wait until all the Tasks return. The code looks similar to the following.

```
Tasks<MyClass>[] tasks = .../Create List of Tasks and Start using TaskFactory.StartNew(..) etc.

Task.WaitAll(tasks);         //Wait until all tasks complete before continuing.
```

When my tasks return and are completed, if they meet certain criteria, the results will be aggregated into a list to be handled at a later time. While each tasks is running, certain exceptions may be thrown which will 'disqualify' the task result from being added to the aggregate list. I want to be able to throw exceptions within the executing task, and the task to no longer run.

I am aware that there are features such as cancellation tokens and cancellation sources for being able to handle certain events, but they don't seem to allow me to do what I want. Althought it doesn't exist, I would have liked functionality such as subscribing to event handlers on the tasks such as task.OnException or task.OnError,etc. What are my options for accomplishing this functionality with TPL?

Answer (score 2):

After a Task has finished running, you can check the Task.Exception property.

[Task.Exception Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx)

If there was an unhandled exception running the Task, Task.Exception will not be null, it will be a System.AggregateException which will contain the details for one of more exceptions that occured.

You might also try using Task.ContinueWith on each Task, passing in a new Task and a flag of TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted. This new task is executed only if there was an unhandled exception in the original Task.

Comment: Also, be aware that if you use `WaitAll()` and some of the `Task`s throw an exception, `WaitAll()` itself will thrown an `AggregateException` that will contain all of the thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can break a `Task` execution a little bit more into parts with help of [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx). Then you can expose events (?) that will be raised just before `TaskCompletionSource` will `SetResult` or `TryToSetException` methods run.